# How do I fix this order request to a WordPress site via the REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php

function createOrder($selectedGame_id, $quantityToBuy, $totalPrice, $msisdn) {
    $consumer_key = '';  //intentionally removed
    $consumer_secret = '';  //intentionally removed
    
    $order_url = 'https://www.afrolottogh.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders';
    $auth = base64_encode($consumer_key . ":" . $consumer_secret);
    
    $customerExists = checkAndCreateCustomer($msisdn);  //function that checks for the existence of a customer based on the phone number that dialled the USSD code.

    $customer_data = $customerExists ? $customerExists : null;  //if customer exists then the details of the customer would be used to make the order

    if ($customerExists) {
        $order_data = array(
            'payment_method' => 'bacs',
            'payment_method_title' => 'Afro Lotto Checkout',
            'set_paid' => true,
            'billing' => array(
                'first_name' => $customer_data['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $customer_data['last_name'],
                'address_1' => $customer_data['billing']['address_1'],
                'address_2' => $customer_data['billing']['address_2'],
                'city' => $customer_data['billing']['city'],
                'state' => $customer_data['billing']['state'],
                'postcode' => $customer_data['billing']['postcode'],
                'country' => $customer_data['billing']['country'],
                'email' => $customer_data['email'],
                'phone' => $customer_data['billing']['phone']
            ),
            'shipping' => array(
                'first_name' => $customer_data['shipping']['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $customer_data['shipping']['last_name'],
                'address_1' => $customer_data['shipping']['address_1'],
                'address_2' => $customer_data['shipping']['address_2'],
                'city' => $customer_data['shipping']['city'],
                'state' => $customer_data['shipping']['state'],
                'postcode' => $customer_data['shipping']['postcode'],
                'country' => $customer_data['shipping']['country']
            ),
            'line_items' => array(
                array(
                    'product_id' => $selectedGame_id,
                    'quantity' => $quantityToBuy
                )
            ),
            'shipping_lines' => array(
                array(
                    'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
                    'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
                    'total' => $totalPrice
                )
            )
        );
    } else {
        $order_data = array(
            'payment_method' => 'bacs',
            'payment_method_title' => 'Afro Lotto Checkout',
            'set_paid' => true,
            'billing' => array(
                'first_name' => $msisdn,
                'last_name' => 'USSD',
                'address_1' => 'USSD',
                'address_2' => '',
                'city' => 'USSD',
                'state' => 'AH',
                'postcode' => '',
                'country' => 'GH',
                'email' => $msisdn . '@gmail.com',
                'phone' => $msisdn
            ),
            'shipping' => array(
                'first_name' => $msisdn,
                'last_name' => 'USSD',
                'address_1' => 'USSD',
                'address_2' => '',
                'city' => 'USSD',
                'state' => 'AH',
                'postcode' => '',
                'country' => 'GH'
            ),
            'line_items' => array(
                array(
                    'product_id' => $selectedGame_id,
                    'quantity' => $quantityToBuy
                )
            ),
            'shipping_lines' => array(
                array(
                    'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
                    'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
                    'total' => $totalPrice
                )
            )
        );
    }
    
    // Send request to create order
    $ch = curl_init($order_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($order_data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    // Process response
    $order_response = json_decode($response, true);
    
    // Check if order creation was successful
    if (isset($order_response['id'])) {
        return "Order created successfully. Order ID: " . $order_response['id'];
    } else {
        return "Failed to create order. Error: " . $order_response['message'];
    }
}

?>
```

My code above doesn't create the order as intended, I am making an order request to a WordPress site using the REST API via a USSD system.

So I used **Postman** to test out the API connection to the site by purchasing a live product using the default API endpoint for creating orders and **it worked**

My challenge is **how to make the PHP file be able to do this** because every parameter needed has been provided in the PHP code yet no order shows up on the WordPress site

```
{
  "payment_method": "bacs",
  "payment_method_title": "Afro Lotto Checkout",
  "set_paid": true,
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "address_1": "123 Main St",
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "12345",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "customer@example.com",
    "phone": "123456789"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "address_1": "123 Main St",
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "12345",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "line_items": [
    {
      "product_id": 41660,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ],
  "shipping_lines": [
    {
      "method_id": "flat_rate",
      "method_title": "Flat Rate",
      "total": "5.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the value of the $response variable:

```
    Order creation response: {
   "code":"rest_invalid_param",
   "message":"Invalid parameter(s): billing, shipping, shipping_lines",
   "data":{
      "status":400,
      "params":{
         "billing":"billing[first_name] is not of type string.",
         "shipping":"shipping[first_name] is not of type string.",
         "shipping_lines":"shipping_lines[0][total] is not of type string."
      },
      "details":{
         "billing":{
            "code":"rest_invalid_type",
            "message":"billing[first_name] is not of type string.",
            "data":{
               "param":"billing[first_name]"
            }
         },
         "shipping":{
            "code":"rest_invalid_type",
            "message":"shipping[first_name] is not of type string.",
            "data":{
               "param":"shipping[first_name]"
            }
         },
         "shipping_lines":{
            "code":"rest_invalid_type",
            "message":"shipping_lines[0][total] is not of type string.",
            "data":{
               "param":"shipping_lines[0][total]"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[postman test results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2bdT.png)

Comment: Some debugging info (like the value of `$response` would be nice to have available.

Comment: @Luuk, I've appended the value of `$response` in my question update. You can check it out

Comment: I have seen it, and applied some formatting to this so it is better readable. Now you should do some debugging to solve the individual errors, like "Invalid parameter" and "billing[first_name] is not of type string"........ succes with [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=debugging+PHP)